# pentaho spoon - change owner of created dir/files

Tags: pentaho, kettle

is there an easy way to create files/directories with a different owner to the account being used to run pentaho? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a step to execute a shell script then run chown if you run Linux.
For Windows environments, if you have UnixTools, it has chown.